# How to reload a picture from a webcam and display it in multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('reloadImages()', 2000); // 2 seconds
});
function reloadImages()
{
   $('#picone').attr('src', 'http://www.someserver/pic.jpg?' + Math.random());
}

</script>

<title>Webcam</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="first">
<img src="pic.jpg" id="picone" border="1" />
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I copy/clone the picture and display it in a second/third/fourth... whatever div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the picture is to remain the same (and I assume it is?) then you don't need to clone it. So if you had two more images such as:

```
<img src="pic.jpg" id="pictwo" border="1" />
<img src="pic.jpg" id="picthree" border="1" />
```

Then you can just do:

```
$('#picone, #pictwo, #picthree').attr('src', 'http://www.someserver/pic.jpg?' + Math.random());
```

This of course may not be what you want...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your HTML for second, third, fourth... div structure look like below:

```
<div id="first">
    <img src="pic.jpg" id="picone" border="1" />
</div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
<div id="fourth"></div>
```

Then you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#second, #third, #fourth').each(function(){
        $(this).prevAll("#first").children("img").clone().appendTo($(this));
    });
});
```